# Selected value in html.dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Can someone please help me with this? I have:

`@Html.DropDownList("ddlExperience", new SelectList(ViewBag.ddlExperience), "Select Experience")` in cshtml

ddlExperience is a List in view bag.

I would like to set in the dropdownlist a value from the data base. how can i do it?

Comment: can you put the class of (ddlExperience)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the selected value to the (SelectList) first:

```
SelectList tMyList = new SelectList(ViewBag.ddlExperience,"Key","Value",SelectedValueFromDatabase);

@Html.DropDownList("ddlExperience", tMyList , "Select Experience")
```